# What are all the spaces in the /etc/fstab for?

Tags: configuration, fstab

I get that I can use `mount` to set up `/` directories and that I can use the `/etc/fstab` to remount them on reboot.

Testing the fstab file is also fun with `mount -faV`.

When I'm looking at the fstab file, the number of space is disconcerting. I would have expected one space (like a separator between command parameters) or four spaces (like a tab). I'm seeing seven spaces at a time, almost as convention.

My question is: **What are all the spaces in the /etc/fstab for?**

(Perhaps also - Will it matter if I get the wrong number?)

Comment: Also very nice if you wanted more readable structur `mount | column -t` :)

Comment: "_...four spaces (like a tab)_".  These young whippersnappers:-) Tabs (once they were standardised) were originally every **eight** characters ([see Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_key)).

Comment: "Testing the fstab file is also fun.." Running *anything* on Linux can be a fun pasttime.

Comment: @TripeHound _"see Wiki"_. These old grey(beards|hairs) ... quote: _A wiki is a hypertext publication collaboratively edited and managed by its own audience_ (see [Wiki_pedia_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki)) ... sorry, could not resist. ️

Comment: @0xC0000022L At least us old grey-both can get italics in links to work: [Wiki*pedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiki) :-)

Comment: @TripeHound Well, I didn't want to spend too much time on such trivialities. Presumably I could have used `<em>` or `<i>` to get the effect. But nice rebuttal ;)

Comment: @0xC0000022L Single asterisks instead of underscores do the trick.

Comment: @TripeHound yeah, with a little effort [I could have simply peeked](https://stackapps.com/q/8296/33569)  ... usually `*` (whether single or not) won't work without having at least a space. Which is why I opted for `_` to make it visible, btw. Guess there are a few *too many* Markdown renderers available 

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The number of spaces is a way to cosmetically separate the columns/fields. It has no meaning other than that. I.e. **no the amount of white space between columns does not matter**.

The space between columns is comprised of white space (including tabs), and the columns themselves, e.g. comma-separated options, mustn't contain unquoted white space.

From the `fstab(5)` man page:

> [...] fields on each line are separated by tabs or spaces.

and

> If the name of the mount point contains spaces these can be escaped as `\040'.

#### Example

With the following lines alignment using solely a single tab becomes hard to achieve. In the end the `fstab` without white space looks messier than what you consider disconcerting now.

```
/dev/md3 /data/vm btrfs defaults 0   0
/var/spool/cron/crontabs /etc/crontabs bind defaults,bind
//bkpsrv/backup /mnt/backup-server cifs iocharset=utf8,rw,credentials=/etc/credentials.txt,file_mode=0660,dir_mode=0770,_netdev
```

Can you still see the "columns"?

Comment: You wouldn't see the "columns" anyway because some line have very long "column" and anyway any line can be longer than 80 columns and so might display "badly" when you do `cat /etc/fstab` in a small terminal, not to mention the use of UUID! So you'll end up bothering adding spaces all over the file.

Comment: @cylgalad Use `less -S` then. Displaying tabular data on screens with small widths is always an issue.

Comment: @cylgalad True the spaces are not as helpful as they were back when the convention with spaces was introduced. In those days the length of each field was still short enough to stay within the column, and the columns were narrow enough to fit all of them in 80 characters.

Comment: And here I am just realizing all that time spent counting spaces were just a waste.

Comment: "mustn't contain unquoted white space"  So there's no way to break up long lines to make them more readable?

Comment: @endolith no idea, I suggest you ask that as a separate question, though, if you're interested in getting an answer ;)

Answer (score 17):

The spaces or tabs delimit the fields.  Use as few or as many as suits.  If you find fstab a little unreadable try using `column` to prettify it.

[image: example of column -t usage for fstab]

Comment: Ooh `column` is nice

Comment: In fact, on my main computer `fstab`, `column` makes it less readable than `cat`!

Answer (score 0):

`getmntent` raises a **parse error** if a line exceeds the character limit. (`getmntent` is the recommended way to read /etc/fstab).

`man getmntent` reveals:

> The getmntent() function reads the next line of the filesystem
>   description file from stream and returns a pointer to a structure
>   containing the broken out fields from a line in the file.

As can be seen from `getmtent_r`, the structure `mount` used for storing file descriptor info is stored as an array of `buflen` - so the parse error occurs for larger entries than `buflen`.

So this design was chosen because the `\` escape character will not work in `fstab` for multiple line breaks in a single entry.

You can easily verify this, and the difference is **NOT** just cosmetic...

Comment: It seems like too many characters per line might in fact cause problems. The [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/getmntent) isn't very clear about this. The `mntent` struct itself only contains pointers. Technically the C strings behind them could have arbitrary length. However, no dynamic memory management seems to be involved, instead the man page mentions a static area of memory which is used, so I the size _has_ to be limited. Do you have a source you can point us to for further information (like the max. length of the strings/line)?